# CakePHP app working remotely but not on local machine

Tags: apache, cakephp, windows-server-2003, xampp

I have a CakePHP app which I have been developing on a remote server.  Everything is working fine on the remote server.

I'm now trying to install it on a machine with a fresh install of XAMPP.  Cake is timing out. Apache is working - other things, such as phpMyAdmin, work fine.  I am running Apache through port 8000, as IIS is using port 80.  The OS is Windows Server 2003.

When trying to access the app, it times out, with the following error:

**Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\cake\libs\debugger.php on line 247**

I have turned URL rewriting off, that hasn't solved the problem.

I have been trying to track down the source of the problem by echoing things and then exiting the script in the cake core.  I found that the script was timing out (with the same error) when the components were trying to load.  I commented out my components array in app_controller, and the script ran a little further.

Now, I have tracked it down this far:

```
Dispatcher::dispatch();
Dispatcher::_invoke();
Controller::constructClasses();
Controller::loadModel();
ClassRegistry::init(); //called on line 635 of Controller in the "else" block of the if (PHP5) statement
```

In ClassRegistry::init(), the script times out on line 141, whic is as follows:

```
${$class} =& new $class($settings);
```

I have no idea where to go from here!  Help much appreciated.

Comment: The class registry is loading both default cake libs as well as third party libs you've added.  Does your server have all the libraries that your local development system does?  You should take a look at what string is stored in $class when it times out, that would be the class that it's failing to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after following the problem a bit further, I found that the problem was coming up in Model::construct.  It turns out that the hostname in my database.php file was wrong!  I would have expected a "could not connect to the database..." error.

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem.

To solve this you should do tw0 things.

1) Try to change the debug level 2 in the core.php from the config adn then change it to 0.
2) plz enable this line from the config.
line number 57 in core.php.
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));

regards,
archit.